# How can I fixate form for tablet PC in Delphi XE2?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2, vcl, tablet-pc

I have a problem. I create a fullscreen form in Delphi XE2. Then I run my application on tablet PC with windows 7 on board where screen resolution is 1024x600. Then I rotate tablet PC (now resolution is 600x1024) and I had some problems with elements on form (some buttons are behind the screen, etc.). Can I configure project so that when I turn the tablet PC my form is not rotate?

Comment: Are you using VCL or FMX?

Comment: I use VCL. Is it in principle?

Comment: The approach to fixing your issue is very fundamental to the framework you're using. It's like buying car parts for a Chevy as opposed to parts for a Ford.

Comment: Ok, I understand. If I use VCL can I fix my situation?

Comment: Why don't you fix the real problem? Nobody likes reading things sidewise. Why don't you make your program work with rotation instead of against it?

Comment: Because owner of this program don't want see our program in portrait orientation. I said him that we'll need adapt program for this situation (I think this is necessary and logically), but he don't want listen this. That's why I want know if it's possible in theory? And how I can do this?

Comment: For Windows 8 there is [SetDisplayAutoRotationPreferences](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn376361%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: It' great, but I need support all systems from Windows XP SP3. But thanks.

Comment: You need to recalibrate your expectations

Answer (score 0):

According to this [MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms812142.aspx) you can detect that the screen has been rotated by listening for the [`WM_DISPLAYCHANGE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd145210.aspx) message.

However, you then face a serious problem. You now need to paint your entire app with a 90 degree rotation. That's going to take quite a bit of doing. I honestly don't believe it to be a tractable solution. I suspect that the viable options are to:

- Modify your program so that it works in both orientations, or
- Configure the device so that it is always in your preferred orientation.

Comment: Thanks, it's useful info. I don't know how I can rotate buttons, memos and etc., hope Google will help me.

Comment: You aren't going to be able to do that